# Show notifications on lockscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, do-not-disturb

My iPhone has always been in do not disturb mode.

Before the most recent iOS update, to 15(.2.1), it used to be the case that notifications would show on my lockscreen. Now they never do.

How can I get notifications to appear on my lockscreen again?

To clarify, I would like the same behaviour I had before updating to iOS 15:

- notifications pile up onto my lockscreen, but do not make sound or vibration
- I never get any kind of pop-up notifications or alert sounds when I have unlocked and am using my phone

Comment: so you are you now in do not disturb mode or not?

Comment: @X_841 yes I am in do not disturb mode

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15 introduced new features to allow for customizing the appearance and behaviour of apps, notifications and the home/lock screen. This includes the so called ["focus"](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-15/) feature. You can now set very specific modes like "work", "sleep", "do not disturb",... and customize the apps shown on the home screen, the notifications and more.

All these settings can be found under settings -> Focus. In your case you'd need to select Do not disturb now and under "allowed notifications" enable apps/people.

Comment: It looks like I hav to add them one-by-one, and will have to manually add all future apps and contacts. Also it looks like this will send me notifications even while my phone is not locked. I want to retain the previous behaviour: when i am using my phone, no notifications at all. When I am not using my phone, notifications pile up on lock screen.